# WCF streamed message download time

Tags: wcf

I have a streamed service. The message returned from the operation has a stream as the only body member, which is a stream to a file in the file system. I wonder if there's a way to record how much time it takes to the client to consume such file, from the server?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can go - return from server not only stream, but data structure, contains file size as well.

On client - you can use timer and calculate time against already read vs took time vs full file size.

See this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20364/Progress-Indication-while-Uploading-Downloading-Fi